# How do I check the ulimit for another user and change open files?

Tags: shell, ulimit

I have a process running as the gearman user and I want to change `open files` to avoid getting this nasty error:

> ERROR 2014-09-12 17:49:14.000000 [  main ] accept(Too many open files) -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:788

How can I run ulimit as another user on Ubuntu and change open files?  I don't currently login as gearman but I do have root access.  I tried doing this:

```
su gearman --shell /bin/bash --command "ulimit -n"
```

as recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user) but nothing get's output:

```
$ su gearman --shell /bin/bash --command "ulimit -n"
Password: 
$
```

Answer (score 31):

Revisiting this just because I stumbled across it during a Google search and found [Tony](https://superuser.com/users/357331/tony)'s comment to be useful: while it's true that limits are placed at the process level, the way you would determine the limits in place for a particular user would be to find the processes they've started and then check the `proc/${id}/limits`.

Specifically:

```
$ ps -u username  # look up processes owned by user
$ sudo grep 'open files' /proc/${id}/limits  # find "Max open files" line for process ID
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, used it to find out the current ulimit for the redis user on Debian.

Answer (score 8):

When you run the `ulimit` command it only affects the process that is running `ulimit` (the shell) and all subprocesses. So when you run `bash --command "ulimit -n"`, it only affects the number of open files for that instance of bash, then bash exits, thus future processes are not affected.

So to accomplish what you want (to increase the open file limit for your real process), it probably makes more sense to edit `limits.conf` to boost the open file limit for your specific gearman user.

See examples of limits.conf elsewhere or [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf).

Comment: That is also what I found but I'd love to be able to check if it "took effect."  I don't get the problem I was having anymore so I'm sure it did

Comment: This is how you check `more /proc/<proc_id>/limits`  ...maybe worth adding to answer

Comment: Worth mentioning the location of limits.conf too: `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `su - <USERNAME> -c ulimit' -Hn'`.
I just tested it on CEntOS 7, and it works.

Comment: This won't work if `<USERNAME>` is unable to login (has the nologin shell).